# Asp.net MVC Checkbox binding with string format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Quoted With New Combo Endorsement</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Quoted_With_New_Combo_Endorsement, new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Yes", Value = "Yes"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "No", Value = "No"},

        }, "Select the Value", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

---

How to convert this code to the checkbox for(Yes/NO)?

**Reminder: datatype can't be changed to bool**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in a project and it's working fine.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Scan in Colour?</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="radio-group">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ScanInColour, "Yes", 
              new { @id = "ScanInColourYes", @class = "form-control" })
            <span>Yes</span>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ScanInColour, "No", 
              new { @id = "ScanInColourNo", @class = "form-control" })
            <span>No</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be a radio-button because it either yes or no?

Instead of the @Html.DropDownListFor use:

```
@Html.RadioButton("YesNo","Yes")  
@Html.RadioButton("YesNo","No")
```